# Making background image out of a div and make it auto resize

Tags: css, image, background, position, resolution

I'm trying to create multiple images stack from top to bottom of the page using empty divs with background-image property applied to them, the problem is that because they don't have a size the browser acts as if they don't exist, is there a hack to fix this? when I add 'width' and 'height' of 'auto' it responses as though I'm not adding any elements to the div. If the "background-size" is set to 'cover' they stack one on top of the other.
Here's a photo of a mockup of what I want my final result to look like:
http://i58.tinypic.com/9uptlw.jpg

Here's the code:

```css
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* end of browser styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);

#logo {
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

nav {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 padding: 5px 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10px;
}
nav li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
body {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
}
#bg1 {
 background: url(../images/wedding.png) no-repeat center center;
 /*width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;*/
 background-size: cover;
}
#bg2 {
 background: url(../images/earrings.png) no-repeat;
 /*width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;*/
 background-size: cover;
}
#bg3 {
 background: url(../images/watch.png) no-repeat;
 /*width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;*/
 background-size: cover;
}
#bg4 {
 background: url(../images/lightning.png) no-repeat;
 /*width: 1280px;
 height: 720px;*/
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SD עיצובים</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header div="mainHeader">
    <nav div="mainNav">
     <ul>
      <img id="logo" src="images/title.png"/>
      <li><a href="index.html">דף הבית</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
      <li><a href="jewelery.html">תכשיטים</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <div id="bg1"></div>
   <div id="bg2"></div>
   <div id="bg3"></div>
   <div id="bg4"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```css
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* end of browser styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);

#logo {
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

nav {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 padding: 5px 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10px;
}
nav li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}

html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%}
#bg1 {
 background: url(../images/wedding.png) no-repeat;
 display: block;
 height: 1920px;
 width: 1080px;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SD עיצובים</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header div="mainHeader">
    <nav div="mainNav">
     <ul>
      <img id="logo" src="images/title.png"/>
      <li><a href="index.html">דף הבית</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
      <li><a href="jewelery.html">תכשיטים</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <div id="bg1"></div>
   <div id="bg2"></div>
   <div id="bg3"></div>
   <div id="bg4"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated again boy you are a hard one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You propably just need to add

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.element { display: block; }
```

and add element class to the divs/lis/whatever or just directly style it

elements that are inline have no height and width they are treated not like a box, and also body and html need to have at least 100% height in this case

**EDIT**

Dude you didnt understand set `.nav li` to `display: block` (!!!) and not inline and give it height in px it MUST work I just tried

my first suggestion was to add element class to the li but now use my edited answer and it WILL work

**EDIT 2**

then add `class="element"` to each of those bg divs and css like I wrote above, then the divs need some height, because how does the browser know what height should this empty div have?

html `<div id="bg1" class="element"></div>` and css `.element { display: block; height: 600px; }`

**EDIT 3**

This is my last attempt:

http://zapraszam.net/public/articles/dummy/

Dude WHAT DOESNT WORK?!

You added the CSS WRAPPED IN COMMENTS?!

You are a hard one.

Comment: The nav isn't my problem the problem is the images that need to be stacked beneath it, they don't appear because they don't have a form until I add to them an actual size rather than a property like 'auto' if you noticed I've excluded from the code "width = 1280; height = 720px " because I wanted to see if the resolution was the problem and it was. I tired your suggestion and I turned the div into a block element but it didn't make any change. And it has nothing to do with the cache because I've tired multiple browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the patience Prozi, I tried it and it didn't work. I'll edit my thread right now to show you.

Comment: after you see that it works on the link I posted, update your question with the right code as I will remove this example from my server within few days and accept my answer finally

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and I've used 'padding-bottom: 50%' instead of an actual resolution so it would really be responsive.